# How to validate formik initial values on mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm trying to validate the initial values of my form that I retrieved from an API.

[image]

Even passing `validateOnForm: true` it isn't working

I found that issue and it seems that Formik is not able to validate initial values https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/288

I'm using a library called [formup](https://github.com/jungsoft/formup) and we have to pass a schema and it returns all Formik components.

```
 const {
    formikForm,
    Form,
    FormInputGroup,
    FormInputGroupItem,
    submitForm,
    FormInput
  } = useFormup(schema, {
    onSubmit: handleFormSubmit,
    validateOnMount: true
  });
```

We can pass formik options as the second argument of the hook

Comment: Please add an [mre] to show how you are trying to do this.

Comment: @zero298 Just added

Comment: live, ready to edit and run - prepare a codesandbox